# jQuery Datatable jEditable refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

I am using jQuery datatable and Jeditable plugin to edit first column of my table. Jeditable is working fine that it updates the db table and shows the edited value on the table but it only does so after refreshing the page. I want it to be updated without refreshing the page. Here is my code:

## JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var objTable = $(".example").DataTable(
{
    "info": false,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
});

$( '.edit' ).each( function()
{

$( this ).editable( 'UpdateDBTableURL',
    {

    'width' : '90%',
    'height' : '80%',
    'tooltip' : 'Click to Edit',
     submit : 'Save',
     cancel : 'Cancel',
     cssclass : "editable",
    'submitdata' :
        {
        'sCompanyID': CompanyID,
        'sAction': 'EditLabel'
        },
     'onClick' : 'submit'

    } );

} );

});
```

## HTML CODE

```
<table class="example" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="edit" id="101">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Mary Kom</td>
      <td>2401 N Main St</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="edit" id="102"></td>
     <td>David Kom</td>
     <td>2401 N Main St</td>    
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to fine tune this but I used the datatable createRow function to add the jedit as the row is being built.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var objTable = $(".example").DataTable(
        {
            "info": false,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            "order": [[1, "asc"]],
            "createdRow": function (row, data) {

                $(row).children(":nth-child(1)").editable('UpdateDBTableURL',
                {

                    'width': '90%',
                    'height': '80%',
                    'tooltip': 'Click to Edit',
                    submit: 'Save',
                    cancel: 'Cancel',
                    cssclass: "editable",
                    'submitdata':
                        {
                            'sCompanyID': CompanyID,
                            'sAction': 'EditLabel'
                        },
                    'onClick': 'submit'

                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: and another possibility is to put it in the DataTable - initComplete

Comment: Its still refereshing the page after I edit the cell and hit Save. I am trying not to refresh page and do it inline editing.